# How do I add an Action Bar/App bar in AppCompat v21?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I need some help from you guys. I'm trying to add an action bar to the new appcompact (AppCompat v21) theme because I don't see any bar when I run the app. By the way, the app is only the basic "Hello World" app.
The only things I changed are `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in Android Manifest and add the module dependency and jars from the new appcompat v7.
Maybe it's something wrong with my SDK, but I already installed/unistalled Android Support library.
I've included an image below of the app.

[image: the app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to extend *ActionBarActivity* also.

Comment: But I didn't disable any Action Bar and the theme is Theme.Appcompat

Comment: Check if the activity in the "HelloWorld" class extends ActionBarActivity to get ActionBar. Like this:
`public class HelloWorld extends ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Thanks for help. This new AppCompat v21 gave me a headache. :D